# ASP.NET 7 - Routing to SPA vs. Controller

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, routes, single-page-application, .net-7.0

Im trying to setup a new ASP.NET 7 WebApplication with a React-SPA and Api-Controllers.

The problem Im facing is, that every request just hits the SPA, even if a controller should handle the request.

I use the following code to setup my app:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();


app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // in dev mode manually start SPA server using: 'npm run start' in ClientApp folder
        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
    }
});
```

When I use the old approach it works, but gives me a pragma warning:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // in dev mode manually start SPA server using: 'npm run start' in ClientApp folder
        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
    }
});
```

How can I do this in a "modern" way?